# Does an Indian need a visa to visit the Schengen area as a tourist?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, france, switzerland

I am an Indian passport holder but Permanent Resident (PR) of Australia.

Do I need a visa for Switzerland and France to visit as a tourist?

Comment: Yes you need a visa.  Did you attempt to research this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need a Schengen visa. No special exemptions exist for holders of any other visas or permanent residencies, however it should be fairly straightforward to receive a Schengen visa as a PR of a stable country.